# content of page is not displaying wordpress getting blank page

Tags: wordpress

am working with developing a wordpress website here am not getting the content of the page am getting blank page

" media="screen" />

1stWebDesigner PHP Template

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
```

```
<h2>1stWebDesigner PHP Template</h2>
```

```
<ul>

<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=');?>
</ul>

</div> <!-- end #nav -->

<div id="content">

     <?php if(have_posts()) :while (have_posts()) : the_posts();?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif;?>

</div> <!-- end #content -->

<div id="sidebar">
```

#### Navigation

Home

About Us

Links

Portfolio

Contact

#### Box Two

Link Here

Link Here

Link Here

Link Here

Link Here

#### Box Three

Link Here

Link Here

Link Here

Link Here

Link Here

```
</div> <!-- end #sidebar -->
```

Copyright &copy 2010 [1stWebDesigner.com PHP Template](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com)

```
    </div> <!-- End #wrapper -->

</body>
```

```
i used this code to display the content but am getting blank page
```

Comment: enable debugging in wp-config.php file and check.

Comment: i enabled debugging in wp-config.php file even though am getting the blank page

Comment: This is only content in your page template? If not please post full template code.

Comment: This question might be more suited for the wordpress SO site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); in wp-config.php

Comment: i set that that true in wp-config.php even though am getting the same blank page